# Unable to start apache2 as it throws an error

Tags: apache2

I have very limited knowledge in Ubuntu and I'm getting an error when I try to start the **apache2** server (seen below)

```
root@ns3016274:/etc/apache2/sites-available# sudo service apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2                                                                                                 (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 *
 * The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems
```

I did reinstall apache2, but still I'm receiving the same issue.

Comment: Looks like you have defined the same port in multiple places. In your case, I presume its **80**. Have you? can you run `grep -ri listen /etc/apache2` and see.

Comment: root@ns3016274:/etc/apache2/sites-available# grep -ri listen /etc/apache2
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:Listen 80 443
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:        Listen 443
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:        Listen 443
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:# Include list of ports to listen on when i ran the command I'm getting the above result

Comment: Have you ever gotten that error before?

Comment: no, i have 8080 assign to flussoinc 8080 port

Comment: Can I sent PM to you ? if Yes how ? new to the forum and cant find PM

Comment: Thanks for the help, I fixed the issue. 80 was assign to another web service

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right there in the message: `(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80`. When `apache2` tried to use the `bind` system call to start listening to port 80, it failed, because some other process had already succeeded with its `bind` call.

Which other process? `man lsof` leads one to:

```
sudo lsof -i TCP:80
```

Since I don't serve port 80, let's look at port 22 (`sshd`) on my system:

```
$ sudo lsof -i  TCP:22
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    1686 root    3u  IPv4  13939      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd    1686 root    4u  IPv6  13941      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I fixed the issue. 80 was assign to another web service